# Sitecore, how to use regex pattern in parameter to search for script tags with FatalError

Tags: regex, validation, sitecore7.2

I'm currently trying to use the Parameters field to search for script tags but can't quite get it to work. The current Parameter I'm using is:

```
Pattern=^<script[^>]*>$&Text=Field "script" is not a valid entry.&Result=FatalError
```

This currently throws an error when my text field is `<script>Test</script>` which is wanted but it also throws an error when my text field is `Test`

I have tried other patterns including

```
Pattern=^<script>$&Text=Field "script" is not a valid entry.&Result=FatalError
Pattern=^<script[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script[^>]*>$&Text=Field....
```

The second pattern mentioned acts just like the first, no surprise there.

The third pattern doesn't throw any errors no matter what is entered into the text box.

Comment: A regex will break trying to parse HTML or XML content: [Not the best tool for the job.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Use a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `<script[^>]*>` should work for you

Usage: `Pattern=<script[^>]*>&Text=Field "script" is not a valid entry.&Result=FatalError`

The regex currently used are not working in your code as it uses anchors `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line).

`^<script[^>]*>$`
`^<script>$`
`^<script[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script[^>]*>$`